# How to summarize an array with group and rollup from d3-array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, alasql

I'm trying to use [d3-array](https://github.com/d3/d3-array) to generate two summaries of an array of objects:

- What actions did each teacher perform?
- What posts did each teacher edit?

This is my current approach:

```
const data = [
  { post_id: 47469, action: "reply", teacher_username: "John" },
  { post_id: 47469, action: "edit", teacher_username: "John" },
  { post_id: 47468, action: "reply", teacher_username: "John" },
  { post_id: 47465, action: "reply", teacher_username: "Mary" },
  { post_id: 47465, action: "edit", teacher_username: "Mary" },
  { post_id: 47467, action: "edit", teacher_username: "Mary" },
  { post_id: 46638, action: "reply", teacher_username: "Paul" },
];

const teacherSummary = [
  ...d3.rollup(
    data,
    (x) => x.length,
    (d) => d.teacher_username,
    (d) => d.action
  ),
]
  .map((x) => {
    return {
      teacher_username: x[0],
      num_edits: x[1].get("edit") || 0,
      num_replies: x[1].get("reply") || 0,
    };
  })
  .sort((a, b) => d3.descending(a.num_edits, b.num_edits));
// [
//   { "teacher_username": "Mary", "num_edits": 2, "num_replies": 1 },
//   { "teacher_username": "John", "num_edits": 1, "num_replies": 2 },
//   { "teacher_username": "Paul", "num_edits": 0, "num_replies": 1 }
// ]

const postIdsByTeacher = d3.rollups(
  data.filter((x) => x.action === "edit"),
  (v) => [...new Set(v.map((d) => d.post_id))].join(", "), // Set() is used to get rid of duplicate post_ids
  (d) => d.teacher_username
);
// [
//  ["John","47469"],
//  ["Mary","47465, 47467"]
// ]
```

I'm flexible on the output format. What I'd like to optimize for is efficiency and clarity:

- Could I get both summaries in a single `rollup` call? Maybe by adding `edited_post_ids` to `teacherSummary`.
- It seems there should be a more elegant approach to replace the `[...Map/Set]` calls

Edit: Out of curiosity, I also tried this approach using [alasql](http://alasql.org/). Except for the nulls in `edited_post_ids`, it almost works.

```
sql = alasql(`
select
  teacher_username,
  count(case when action = 'reply' then 1 end) num_replies,
  count(case when action = 'edit' then 1 end) num_edits,
  array(case when action = 'edit' then post_id end) as edited_post_ids
from ?
group by teacher_username
`, [data])
// [ 
//   { teacher_username: "John", num_replies: 2, num_edits: 1, edited_post_ids: [null, 47469, null], }, 
//   { teacher_username: "Mary", num_replies: 1, num_edits: 2, edited_post_ids: [null, 47465, 47467], }, 
//   { teacher_username: "Paul", num_replies: 1, num_edits: 0, edited_post_ids: [null], },
// ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function signature for [`d3.rollup`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#rollup) is:

*d3.rollup(iterable, reduce, ...keys)*

Which on the face of it says you can provide one operation in `reduce` e.g. counting or summation or some other operation - but just one.

For your output, you're looking for two different operations

- counting the replies and edits, and
- an array operation to get `post_id`s where `action == "edit"`

As soon as you made the choice to use `(x) => x.length` you've kind of cut off the opportunity to use a different `reduce` operation. Arguably `d3.rollup` isn't the function you need if you have multiple operations?

Still you can add `edited_post_ids` to `teacherSummary` by simply reaching back into the original data and applying a `filter` then `map`:

```js
const data = [
  { post_id: 47469, action: "reply", teacher_username: "John" },
  { post_id: 47469, action: "edit", teacher_username: "John" },
  { post_id: 47468, action: "reply", teacher_username: "John" },
  { post_id: 47465, action: "reply", teacher_username: "Mary" },
  { post_id: 47465, action: "edit", teacher_username: "Mary" },
  { post_id: 47467, action: "edit", teacher_username: "Mary" },
  { post_id: 46638, action: "reply", teacher_username: "Paul" },
];

const teacherSummary = [...d3.rollup(
  data,
  v => v.length,
  d => d.teacher_username,
  d => d.action
)].map(d => {
  return {
    teacher_username: d[0],
    num_edits: d[1].get("edit") || 0,
    num_replies: d[1].get("reply") || 0,
    edited_post_ids: data
      .filter(x => x.action === "edit" & x.teacher_username == d[0])
      .map(x => x.post_id)
  }
});
  
console.log(teacherSummary);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

An alternative is to not use `d3.rollup`/`d3.rollups` and use [`d3.groups`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#groups) instead. The [source](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/src/group.js) for `rollup` and `group` are all calls to `nest` btw. You lose the counting that `rollup` did for you and have to implement it yourself. This example reads a bit more like the SQL example:

```js
const data = [
  { post_id: 47469, action: "reply", teacher_username: "John" },
  { post_id: 47469, action: "edit", teacher_username: "John" },
  { post_id: 47468, action: "reply", teacher_username: "John" },
  { post_id: 47465, action: "reply", teacher_username: "Mary" },
  { post_id: 47465, action: "edit", teacher_username: "Mary" },
  { post_id: 47467, action: "edit", teacher_username: "Mary" },
  { post_id: 46638, action: "reply", teacher_username: "Paul" },
];

// compare with
// select
//   teacher_username,
//   count(case when action = 'reply' then 1 end) num_replies,
//   count(case when action = 'edit' then 1 end) num_edits,
//   array(case when action = 'edit' then post_id end) as 
// edited_post_ids
// from ?
// group by teacher_username

const teacherSummary = d3.groups(data, d => d.teacher_username)
  .map(k => {
    return {
      teacher_username: k[0],
      num_edits: k[1].filter(k2 => k2.action == "edit").length,
      num_replies: k[1].filter(k2 => k2.action == "reply").length,
      edited_post_ids: k[1].filter(k2 => k2.action == "edit").map(k3 => k3.post_id)
    }
  });
  
console.log(teacherSummary);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

As a side-note then, you can boil down `postIdsByTeacher` to below, and avoid `new Set(etc)` type stuff:

```js
const data = [
  { post_id: 47469, action: "reply", teacher_username: "John" },
  { post_id: 47469, action: "edit", teacher_username: "John" },
  { post_id: 47468, action: "reply", teacher_username: "John" },
  { post_id: 47465, action: "reply", teacher_username: "Mary" },
  { post_id: 47465, action: "edit", teacher_username: "Mary" },
  { post_id: 47467, action: "edit", teacher_username: "Mary" },
  { post_id: 46638, action: "reply", teacher_username: "Paul" },
];

const postIdsByTeacher = d3.rollups(
  data.filter(d => d.action === "edit"),
  v => [].concat(v.map(k => k.post_id)),
  d => d.teacher_username
);

console.log(postIdsByTeacher);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

But my gut feel is the value of using `d3.rollup` is going to be when you want to do the standard summation and counting kind of stuff.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. I forgot to mention that the `new Set()` stuff is needed to avoid duplicate post_ids.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up simplifying @Robin Mackenzie's last suggestion:

```
const uniq = require('lodash.uniq');
const teacherSummary = d3
  .groups(data, (d) => d.teacher_username)
  .map(([teacher_username, actions]) => {
    const edits = actions.filter((x) => x.action == "edit").map((x) => x.post_id);
    const replies = actions.filter((x) => x.action == "reply").map((x) => x.post_id);
    return {
      teacher_username,
      num_edits: edits.length,
      num_replies: replies.length,
      edited_post_ids: uniq(edits),
      replied_post_ids: uniq(replies),
    };
  })
```